# Friend Modules in OCaml

Tags: module, dependencies, ocaml, friend

I currently have two "layers" of modules that represent identifier-data relationships in a database.

The first layer defines identifier types, such as `IdUser.t` or `IdPost.t` while the second layer defines data types such as `User.t` or `Post.t`. I need all the modules of the first layer to be compiled before the modules of the second layer, because a `Post.t` must hold the `IdUser.t` of its author and the `User.t` holds the `IdPost.t` of the last five posts he visited.

Right now, `IdUser.t` provides functionality that should only ever be used by `User.t`, such as the ability to transform an `IdUser.t` into an `IdUser.current`: for security reasons, this transform must only ever be performed by the function `User.check_password`. Since `IdUser` and `User` are independent modules, I need to define those features as public functions and rely on conventions to avoid calling them anywhere outside of `User`, which is rather dirty. A symmetrical situation happens in `IdPost.mine`:

```
module IdUser : sig
  type t
  type current
  val current_of_t : t -> current (* <--- Should not be public! *)
end = struct 
  type t = string
  type current = string
  let current_of_t x = x
end

module IdPost : sig
  type t
  type mine
  val mine_of_t   : t -> mine (* <--- Should not be public! *)
end = struct 
  type t = string
  type mine = string
  let mine_of_t   x = x
end

module Post : sig 
 (* Should not "see" IdUser.current_of_t but needs IdPost.mine_of_t *)
  val is_mine : IdUser.current -> IdPost.t -> IdPost.mine
end 

module User : sig
  (* Should not "see" IdPost.mine_of_t but needs IdUser.current_of_t *)
  val check_password : IdUser.t -> password:string -> IdUser.current
end
```

Is there a way of defining an `current_of_t : t -> current` function in `IdUser` that can only be called from within module `User` ?

**EDIT**: this was a simplified example of *one* pair of modules, but there's an obvious solution for a single pair that cannot be generalized to multiple pairs and I need to solve this for multiple pairs — about 18 pairs, actually... So, I've extended it to be an example of *two* pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So `IdUser` is in reality an existential type: For `User` there exists a type
`IdUser.current` such that the public `IdUser.t` can be lifted to it. There are a couple of ways to encode this: either functorize `User` as Gasche shows if statically managing the dependence is sufficient, or use first-class modules or objects if you need more dynamism.

I'll work out Gasche's example a bit more, using [private type abbreviations](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual021.html#htoc103) for convenience and to show how to leverage translucency to avoid privatizing implementation types too much. First, and this might be a limitation, I want to declare an ADT of persistent `IDs`:

```
(* File id.ml *)
module type ID = sig
  type t
  type current = private t
end

module type PERSISTENT_ID = sig
  include ID
  val persist : t -> current
end
```

With this I can define the type of `Post`s using concrete types for the `ID`s but with ADTs to enforce the business rules relating to persistence:

```
(* File post.ml *)
module Post
  (UID : ID with type t = string)
  (PID : PERSISTENT_ID with type t = int)
: sig 
  val is_mine : UID.current -> PID.t -> PID.current
end = struct
  let is_mine uid pid =
    if (uid : UID.current :> UID.t) = "me" && pid = 0
      then PID.persist pid
      else failwith "is_mine"
end
```

The same thing with `User`s:

```
(* File user.ml *)
module User
  (UID : PERSISTENT_ID with type t = string)
: sig
  val check_password : UID.t -> password:string -> UID.current
end = struct
  let check_password uid ~password =
    if uid = "scott" && password = "tiger"
      then UID.persist uid
      else failwith "check_password"
end
```

Note that in both cases I make use of the concrete but private `ID` types. Tying all together is a simple matter of actually defining the `ID` ADTs with their persistence rules:

```
module IdUser = struct 
  type t = string
  type current = string
  let persist x = x
end

module IdPost = struct 
  type t = int
  type current = int
  let persist x = x
end

module MyUser = User (IdUser)
module MyPost = Post (IdUser) (IdPost)
```

At this point and to fully decouple the dependencies you will probably need signatures for `USER` and `POST` that can be exported from this module, but it's a simple matter of adding them in.

Comment: I'm afraid there are too many dependencies to handle this as hand-written functors. Could you give a few more details about how first-class modules might help?

Comment: First-class modules will not help you with the dependencies, they'll merely shift the burden of providing the persistence business rule (the method to "open" the existential type) from the module level to the function level, with quite a bit more syntactic overhead.

Perhaps the simplest alternative is to add a parameter of type `ID.t -> ID.persisted` to the functions that need lifting the corresponding `ID`, for instance `val is_mine : IdUser.current -> IdPost.t -> (IdPost.t -> IdPost.mine) -> IdPost.mine`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the latter alternative is not applicable: the entire point is to make sure that the *only* public function that returns `IdPost.mine` is one that actually checks the post is owned by the current user. So, I will not allow any other public `IdPost.t -> IdPost.mine` function to exist.

Comment: @VictorNicollet: The last functional parameter is simply `mine_of_t` explicitly passed to `is_mine` instead of referring to the functor parameter. It is not another restricted policy function.

If this is a matter of policy, that is, of what code combinations are allowed and which are not, I think the static approach is the only sensible one. If this is a matter of safety, that is, of what code combinations make more sense and which do not but are not prohibited, a higher-order solution can be workable. I'm thinking, Haskell would use monads, and it would make sense here too.

Comment: This is not entirely satisfying, but at least it points out why what I'm hoping for is (as of now) impossible. Too bad.

Answer (score 2):

One way that seems to work at least on your simplified example is to group `IdUser` and `User` inside a same module:

```
module UserAndFriends : sig ... end = struct
 module IdUser : sig
  ...
 end = struct
  ...
 end

 module User = struct
   ...
 end
end

module Post : sig 
  val create : (* <--- Should not "see" IdUser.current_of_t *)
    author:IdUser.current -> title:string -> body:string -> IdPost.t
end
```

Hiding the dangerous function(s) in the signature of `UserAndFriends` gives the result you desire. If you do not want to make a big file containing both `IdUser` and `User`, you can use option `-pack` of ocamlc to create `UserAndFriends`. Note that in this case, you must craft your Makefile carefully so that the .cmi files of `IdUser` and `User` are not visible when compiling `Post`. I am not the Makefile specialist for Frama-C, but I think we use separate directories and position the compiler option `-I` carefully.

Comment: How would you extend this to handle the situation where `IdPost` and `Post` also share a private function?

Comment: @Victor I expected you would say something like that. I do not have a general solution. I can only suggest using a submodule inside `IdUser` and `IdPost` each to group all dangerous functions, in order to help avoid using them accidentally.

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing. I hoped there would be a clean way around it.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you parametrize `Post` (and possibly `User` for consistency) by a signature for the `IdUser` module : you would use a signature with `current_of_t` for `User`, and one without for `Post`.

This guarantee that `Post` doesn't use `IdUser` private features, but the public interface of `IdUser` is still too permissive. But with this setup, you have reversed the dependencies, and `IdUser` (the sensitive part) can control its use directly, give itself (with the private part) to `IdUser` and restrict the public signature to the public parts.

```
module type PrivateIdUser = sig
  val secret : unit
end

module type PublicIdUser = sig
end

module type UserSig = sig
  (* ... *)
end
module MakeUser (IdUser : PrivateIdUser) : UserSig = struct
  (* ... *)
end

module IdUser : sig
  include PublicIdUser
  module User : UserSig
end
 = struct
   module IdUser = struct
     let secret = ()
   end
   module User = MakeUser(IdUser)
   include IdUser
end

module Post = struct
  (* ... *)
end
```

*Edit* : Pascal Cuoq's concurrent -- in the temporal sense -- solution is alos very nice. Actually it's simpler and has less boilerplate. My solution adds an abstraction that allows for slightly more modularity, as you can define `User` independently of `IdUser`.

I think which solution is best probably depends on the specific application. If you have a lot of different modules that use `PrivateIdUser` private information, then using functors to write them separately instead of bundling everyone in the same module can be a good idea. If only `User` needs to be in the "private zone" and it's not very big, then Pascal's solution is a better choice.

Finally, while being forced to explicit `Private` and `Public` interfaces can be seen as an additional burden, it is also a way to make the access properties of different modules more explicit that using the position inside the module hierarchy.

Comment: How would you extend this to handle the situation where `IdPost` and `Post` also share a private function?

Comment: Then I would also have `Post` a functor over `IdPost`. Actually I didn't do anything specific to `Post` or `IdPost` in my code, its just about the relation between `IdUser` and either `User` or the rest of the world.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to achieve fine-grained control over signatures with a combination of recursive modules, first-class modules and GADTs, but the limitation would be that all modules should then be inside the same top-level module and unpackings of first-class modules inside the recursive modules should be done in each function separately (not on the module-level as it would cause runtime exception Undefined_recursive_module):

```
module rec M1 : sig
  module type M2's_sig = sig
    val a : int
    val c : float
  end

  module type M3's_sig = sig
    val b : string
    val c : float
  end

  type _ accessor =
    | I'm_M2 : M2.wit -> (module M2's_sig) accessor
    | I'm_M3 : M3.wit -> (module M3's_sig) accessor

  val access : 'a accessor -> 'a

  type wit

  val do_it : unit -> unit
end = struct
  module type M2's_sig = sig
    val a : int
    val c : float
  end

  module type M3's_sig = sig
    val b : string
    val c : float
  end

  type _ accessor =
    | I'm_M2 : M2.wit -> (module M2's_sig) accessor
    | I'm_M3 : M3.wit -> (module M3's_sig) accessor

  module M1 = struct
    let a = 1
    let b = "1"
    let c = 1.
  end

  let access : type a. a accessor -> a =
    function
    | I'm_M2 _ -> (module M1)
    | I'm_M3 _ -> (module M1)

  type wit = W

  let do_it () =
    let (module M2) = M2.(access @@ I'm_M1 W) in
    let (module M3) = M3.(access @@ I'm_M1 W) in
      Printf.printf "M1: M2: %d %s M3: %d %s\n" M2.a M2.b M3.a M3.b
end
and M2 : sig
  module type M1's_sig = sig
    val a : int
    val b : string
  end

  module type M3's_sig = sig
    val b : string
    val c : float
  end

  type _ accessor =
    | I'm_M1 : M1.wit -> (module M1's_sig) accessor
    | I'm_M3 : M3.wit -> (module M3's_sig) accessor

  val access : 'a accessor -> 'a

  type wit

  val do_it : unit -> unit
end = struct
  module type M1's_sig = sig
    val a : int
    val b : string
  end

  module type M3's_sig = sig
    val b : string
    val c : float
  end

  type _ accessor =
    | I'm_M1 : M1.wit -> (module M1's_sig) accessor
    | I'm_M3 : M3.wit -> (module M3's_sig) accessor

  module M2 = struct
    let a = 2
    let b = "2"
    let c = 2.
  end

  let access : type a. a accessor -> a =
    function
    | I'm_M1 _ -> (module M2)
    | I'm_M3 _ -> (module M2)

  type wit = W

  let do_it () =
   let (module M1) = M1.(access @@ I'm_M2 W) in
   let (module M3) = M3.(access @@ I'm_M2 W) in
   Printf.printf "M2: M1: %d %f M3: %d %f\n" M1.a M1.c M3.a M3.c
end
and M3 : sig
  module type M1's_sig = sig
    val a : int
    val b : string
  end

  module type M2's_sig = sig
    val a : int
    val c : float
  end

  type _ accessor =
    | I'm_M1 : M1.wit -> (module M1's_sig) accessor
    | I'm_M2 : M2.wit -> (module M2's_sig) accessor

  val access : 'a accessor -> 'a

  type wit

  val do_it : unit -> unit
end = struct
  module type M1's_sig = sig
    val a : int
    val b : string
  end

  module type M2's_sig = sig
    val a : int
    val c : float
  end

  type _ accessor =
    | I'm_M1 : M1.wit -> (module M1's_sig) accessor
    | I'm_M2 : M2.wit -> (module M2's_sig) accessor

  module M3 = struct
    let a = 3
    let b = "3"
    let c = 3.
  end

  let access : type a. a accessor -> a =
    function
    | I'm_M1 _ -> (module M3)
    | I'm_M2 _ -> (module M3)

  type wit = W

  let do_it () =
    let (module M1) = M1.(access @@ I'm_M3 W) in
    let (module M2) = M2.(access @@ I'm_M3 W) in
    Printf.printf "M3: M1: %s %f M2: %s %f\n" M1.b M1.c M2.b M2.c
end

let () =
  M1.do_it ();
  M2.do_it ();
  M3.do_it ()
```